# Can I kill "repair by keycache"?

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to add an index on a new field I have added to a MyISAM table consisting of 8.5 million rows. The query went from 'REPAIR BY SORTING' to 'REPAIR BY KEYCACHE', which seems to be due to running out of disk space during sorting. I understand keycache repair is not good and will take a long time - so far it's ran for 1.5 hours.

What would happen if I killed this query? Is it likely to damage the table (and database)? Could I not kill this query and do a myisamchk repair?

I have a backup of this table and database, will it save time if I restore and try adding the index again presuming it was caused by disk space?

I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

Same error with me on InnoDB engine. Increased my /mysql mount point and waited for 10mins - restoration started automatically

Mariadb 10.1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).